# How to use Cache helper function in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, caching, laravel-5.4

I'm booting my `Laravel` application by extending the boot method where I'm having a small check point which checks the value in cache. For this I'm using the `Laravel's` own `Illuminate\Foundation` `helper function` `cache`, but unfortunately I'm getting and error, my application code is:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Application as IlluminateApplication;
use LayerShifter\TLDExtract\Extract;

/**
 * Extends \Illuminate\Foundation\Application to override some defaults.
 */
class Application extends IlluminateApplication
{
    /**
     * Is Client.
     *
     * @var boolean
     */
    protected $isClient = false;

    /**
     * Client secret key.
     *
     * @var boolean
     */
    protected $clientSecret;

    /**
     * Client ID.
     *
     * @var boolean
     */
    protected $clientID;

    /**
     * Constructing the class with tenant check
     */
    public function __construct($basePath = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($basePath);

        $this->clientCheck();
    }

    public function clientCheck()
    {
        if($this->isClient = cache('is_client'))
        {
            return $this->isClient;
        }
        else
        {
            $domainData = $this->getDomainSubDomain();
            //Do Check and return the value,
            //Set the values
            // Cache for one day
            $data = //Data which is being recieved
            cache(['is_client' => $data], 1 * 24 * 60);
            return $data;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get Domain and Sub Domain
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getDomainSubDomain()
    {
        $http_req = php_sapi_name() == 'cli' ? 'noetic.com' : $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];
        $extract = new Extract();
        $result = $extract->parse($http_req);
        return array(
            "domain" => $result->getHostname() . '.' . $result->getSuffix(),
            "subDomain" => $result->getSubdomain()
        );
    }
}
```

Error Which I'm getting:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught ReflectionException: Class cache does not exist in 
E:\xamppNew\htdocs\noeticit\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:729 Stack trace: #0 
E:\xamppNew\htdocs\noeticit\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(729): ReflectionClass->__construct('cache') #1 
E:\xamppNew\htdocs\noeticit\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(608): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('cache') #2 
E:\xamppNew\htdocs\noeticit\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(575): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('cache') #3 
E:\xamppNew\htdocs\noeticit\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(728): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('cache') #4 
E:\xamppNew\htdocs\noeticit\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\helpers.php(106): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('cache') #5 
E:\xamppNew\htdocs\noeticit\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\helpers.php(230): app('cache') #6 
E:\ in E:\xamppNew\htdocs\noeticit\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php on line 729
```

Guide me how can I achieve this.

Comment: have you tried using `app("cache")`?

Comment: Maybe the cache service is not included yet. Try using the function in a controller, if this works fine there then clearly the issue is application haven't boot the cache method yet.

Comment: @ParantapParashar: cache is working through controller, but my question is I want to have cache storage check before loading the application, I'm having different set of environment for different domains which needs to be loaded accordingly, FYI you can have a look at this application https://github.com/phanan/koel/blob/master/app/Application.php#L88

Comment: do use Cache at the top and see if that fixes the issue

Comment: @NitishKumar Yes. I understand that. This is what I am saying. If it is not included by the framework yet, you probably need to include it manually or directly use the service class for `cache`. But using class directly can cause problems if cache class is extended or config is changed. The change will not be reflected in your class.

Answer (score -1):

I normally use Redis for this so I follow the below steps

```
composer require predis/predis
```

then go to .env file and change my `CACHE_DRIVER=file` to `CACHE_DRIVER=redis`

and then for Setting data I use

```
Cache::put('key', 'value', $expiresAt);
```

and getting data I use

```
Cache::get('key');
```

Comment: This does not help OP with his problem. This is an _alternative_ but it is not a solution to their question.